# Reputation graph not showing properly

Tags: bug, status-declined, reputation

I don't know whether it's bug or anything. I just hover across the reputation graph of [Mr.Habib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961113/habib?tab=reputation&sort=graph) and I tried to list out the reputation graph from his initial period. Bar's of each day's reputation do not appear at all unless I hover over some area of the graph. At the same time the graph is working properly for small periods of time.

Here is screenshot of it:

> [image]

I have Windows 7 OS and i just saw this problem in Chrome browser

Comment: Always report your browser & OS for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Mat I have mention the details.

Answer (score -1):

No solution, but maybe at least one step towards finding it:

When a large range is selected, the bars of the chart are only 1 pixel wide. And for some odd reason, chrome seems to draw the bars (rectangles) with a white stroke with a width of `0.000001`, which seems to overpaint the bars.

Inspected bars in Chrome:

[image: Chart01]

(For the selected bar, I manually changed the stroke width to 0.0, and then it magically appears...)

In contrast to the inspected bars in Firefox 31: They are painted with a stroke width of `0`, and thus, are painted properly even when they are only 1 pixel wide.

[image: Chart02]

Answer (score -5):

Hmm, works on my Chrome 36.0.1985.125 - regardless, that's a pretty large swath of time to view.

Just stick to the smaller timespans :)